# More / less links not work in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have problems with the function of show more/less text in all internet explorer. Internet explorer don't hide the text, but it is visible all the time. Does anyone know why? In newer safari, chrome, opera, firefox work fine.

```js
function moreLess(initiallyVisibleCharacters) {
 var visibleCharacters = initiallyVisibleCharacters;
 var paragraph = $(".text")
 

 paragraph.each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var wholeText = text.slice(0, visibleCharacters) + "<span class='ellipsis'>... </span><a href='#' class='more'>MORE<i class='fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>" + "<span style='display:none'>" + text.slice(visibleCharacters, text.length) + "<a href='#' class='less'> LESS<i class='fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></span>"
  
  if (text.length < visibleCharacters) {
   return
  } else {
   $(this).html(wholeText)
  }
 });
 $(".more").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide().prev().hide();
  $(this).next().show();
 });
 $(".less").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();
 });
};

moreLess(300);
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: also - it is working fine in my explorer 11

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uwqvt785/

Comment: also - you should probably consider, that there are almost no users left, that is using older explorers - and the time that you spend on optimizing for explorer could be used elsewhere. Be part of the revolution - death to IE!

Comment: @Stender And then, the billionaire businessman who has a once-in-a-life time proposal for you can't access it 'cause he uses IE8 (:

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of the JQuery reference you've referred, I think perhaps the issue is related to the JQuery version. You could also use F12 developer tools to verify whether it contains JavaScript error.

I've made some tests according to your code. And I've found that when using the latest version of Jquery(such as:jquery-3.3.1), the text will be visible all the time in IE8 and older versions. The console bar will show the an error in the following picture.
[the console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1lf7.jpg)

This is because latest versions of jQuery do not support older versions of IE, you should try to use an older version of jQuery like below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

And it may work well, you could see from the capture.
[the running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3DoP.gif)

Last but not at least, do not forget to add .ready() function in your code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   function moreLess(initiallyVisibleCharacters) {
            .................
   }
})
```